# How do I add a 2D Plot along with a surface or mesh plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I would like to have a 2D plot along with a 3D surface or mesh plot - shown by the blue line I drew on the surface plot below. How do I get it?

[image: Surface Plot]

UPDATE: Natan's Solution worked :-) But I now have a new Problem - [How do I add 2 Y axis to my MATLAB Plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321090/how-do-i-add-2-y-axis-to-my-matlab-plot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add to the surf plot another plot using `plot3` where the relevant axis has the limits of the surf plot.

For example:

```
z=peaks(100);
surface(z, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
colormap(hot)
view(30,30); camlight; axis vis3d

x1=linspace(0,100);
hold on
plot3(x1,0*ones(1,numel(x1)),4*sin(x1))
```

[image]