# How do I add 2 Y axis to my MATLAB Plot?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I know this question has been asked before - but none of them deal with a 3D plot with 2 Y axis. My question is a continuation of  - [How do I add a 2D Plot along with a surface or mesh plot in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309153/how-do-i-add-a-2d-plot-along-with-a-surface-or-mesh-plot-in-matlab) or [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/74160-how-do-i-add-a-2d-plot-along-with-a-surface-or-mesh-plot-in-matlab).

I have now successfully managed to add a 2D plot along with a surface plot. See image below -
[image: 2D + 3D Plot] Now my problem is that the range of the 2D plot is so high that the 3D plot is shrunk to look like nothing more than a plane on the ceiling. It is supposed to have variations like the figure in the question I have lined above.

How do I provide a different Y axis for the 2D plot so that the 3D plot is not shrunk like it is here.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just multiply the surface value by some large constant?

Comment: The axis values will not make sense.

Comment: why don't you just normalize your data so the same axis can be used?

Comment: They are normalized. Once set of data ranges between .9 and 1 and the other between .2 and .5. In the above pic I shifted the 0 of the 2D plot by 0.5 to see anything at all. I have 106 (the 4th dimension) such graphs - This is just one. Some are better and some are worse (visually).

Comment: by normalization I mean, max value is set to 1, min value is set to zero. Think that the end result will look the same only without an additional axis...

Comment: A way of normalizing could be: data2Dnorm = 0.5 * (data2D - min(data2D)) / (max(data2D) - min(data2D)); and data3Dnorm = 0.5 * (data2D - min(min(data2D))) / (max(max(data2D)) - min(min(data2D))) + 0.5; So the 2D plot will remain within the bounds of 0 and 0.5 and the 3D surface will remain within the bounds of 0.5 and 1.

Comment: @natan - I have 106 different graphs (4D Data) that have to be compared by value. If I normalize each graph, very different graphs shall look the same. If I normalize it I shall lose the meaning of the data. My surface represents a quantified image quality. The 2D plot is the file compression ratio. The 4th axis (I have a slider in a separate GUI) is compression parameter.

Comment: Why wont you then use `imagesc` to project the 3D data into 2D, and then add a subplot of the 2D plot? the color coding of `imagesc` will be the same anyway.  Why do you need to plot your data in this particular way?

Comment: I gave it a try - http://i.stack.imgur.com/sZGdu.png is a what `imagesc` got me. It does not look all that visually convincing. I apologies if I sound adamant - but I am trying to retain my data fidelity as best as possible. I think I shall temporary go with the subplot until I  find a 2 axis solution. The question is still open.

Comment: You can overlay a second axis, link the axes, add manually a second vertical line with ticks. If I'll find time I will post a solution

Comment: @OlegKomarov - I and a friend have been trying that with limited success (read failure). Looking forward to your solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you can use the DataAspectRatio property to accomplish this. Taking inspiration from the example from the previous post, if we have:

```
 z=peaks(100);
 x1=linspace(0,100);
 plot3(x1,0*ones(1,numel(x1)),40*sin(x1))
 surface(z+40, 'edgecolor', 'none');
```

and then you can use

```
set( gca, 'dataaspectratio', [1.25 1.25 .7] )
view( [-37.5 18] )
```

can work in some cases to help regain some of the range on the surface plot. This method won't work, however, in very extreme cases.